# How to use the incluxdb1-client library of golang to query the data？

Tags: go, influxdb, victoriametrics

My library is github.com/influxdata/influxdb1-client/v2，and I need to use it to operate the VictoriaMetrics, For example, I need to make the following query：

```
sort_desc(avg(idc_bandwidth_5m_data_cube_just_idc_bandwidth_kilobits{idc=~"$cluster", isp=~"$isp"}[5m]) by (idc))
```

What should I do? Or is there another better library to use？ Help me！！！

Can you give me a sample code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid github.com/influxdata/influxdb1-client/v2 can't be used for **reading** data from VcitoriaMetrics. You need a library which can send PromQL/MetricsQL queries via HTTP and parse responses. I'm not sure if there are a good Golang lib for that. I've heard only about [JS lib](https://github.com/samber/prometheus-query-js).

In general, sending queries and parsing responses to VictoriaMetrics or Prometheus is rarely needed. And when needed, it is usually implemented from scratch. Please use the following [link](https://github.com/prometheus/common/blob/7600349dcfe1abd18d72d3a1770870d9800a7801/model/value.go) as a reference.

You might be also interested in the following issue I'm afraid github.com/influxdata/influxdb1-client/v2 can't be used for **reading** data from VcitoriaMetrics. You need a library which can send PromQL/MetricsQL queries via HTTP and parse responses. I'm not sure if there are a good Golang lib for that. I've heard only about [JS lib](https://github.com/samber/prometheus-query-js).

In general, sending queries and parsing responses to VictoriaMetrics or Prometheus is rarely needed. And when needed, it is usually implemented from scratch. Please use the following [link](https://github.com/prometheus/common/blob/7600349dcfe1abd18d72d3a1770870d9800a7801/model/value.go) as a reference.

You might be also interested in the following issue https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics/issues/108